# Distribute IE Trusted Sites Security Zone Sites and Settings using GPO

Tags: internet-explorer, group-policy, windows-domain

Currently I have Windows XP workstations, Windows Server 2008 R2, Active Directory and Domain Services, using IE 8 and IE 7 through out the domain.

I haven't been able to pinpoint this, but how am I able to set all the workstations to have the same list of Trusted Sites, and set the settings of the Zone as the same?

For example, I want to add some internal sites to the Trusted Sites Zone, and set the settings to "Enable" on all options.

Is there a way for me to do this using GPO?  I have been unable to find the proper settings in GPO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.brighthub.com/internet/security-privacy/articles/86425.aspx